# why `font-size` isn't equal to the `height`? so in the right if the <span> is 2rem, on the right I can have 2 small <span>s of 1rem each one

Tags: html, css, font-size, line-height

how can I do a layout like this?

[image]

> basically,
>
>  I have 2 containers in `flexbox`:
>
> - first one with text `"33"`
> - the second one is a grid container:
>
>   - the first one in the grid is `"EUR"`
>   - the second one in the grid is `".49"`

so with this description, I tried to write a structure in HTML using this code

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>

    <div class="price-container">
      <div class="first-price-container">
        <span class="price-big"> 371 </span>
      </div>

      <div class="second-price-container">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small"> 74 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried to use CSS for this, but here is what I get. is totally not correct, since I want that 33 be the perfectly same height as the grid layout:

[image]

> here CSS code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  --small-font: 1rem;
  font-family: poppins;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* space between copies of the container .item */
}

.item {
  display: grid;
}

.price-container {
  display: flex;
}

.second-price-container {
  display: grid;
  font-size: var(--small-font);
}

.price-big {
  font-size: calc(var(--small-font) * 2);
  /* I think that since the grid layout has two text with 1rem height, it will be 2rem (but not seems to work) */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.price-small::before {
  content: ".";
}

.item .date {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>

    <div class="price-container">
      <div class="first-price-container">
        <span class="price-big"> 37 </span>
      </div>

      <div class="second-price-container">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small"> 49 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>

    <div class="price-container">
      <div class="first-price-container">
        <span class="price-big"> 37 </span>
      </div>

      <div class="second-price-container">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small"> 49 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>

    <div class="price-container">
      <div class="first-price-container">
        <span class="price-big"> 37 </span>
      </div>

      <div class="second-price-container">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small"> 49 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- and soo on... repeatedly, however after I will find the correct structure, I will create a function in javascript that generate it -->
</nav>
```

in the code, I thought that if I have two elements with 1rem `font-size`,

 then on the right if I insert near it another text and I write the addition of `1rem+1rem` to be the same height of the grid layout.

seems that there is no correct gap between elements in the grid layout.

---

also, another try was instead of doing `1rem+1rem` , I increased a lot like `1rem*5` and still the problem remains,

 so I think that if the font-size of the bigger increase, then also the other element on the right increase.

---

pls help, this doesn't seem obvious to me. (because this won't happen with height property, only with font-size become wrong)

**question:**

is there a formula for making `font-size == height` ? so I can have pixel-perfect designs without a lot of code.

##### now I will add another code to tell you how I want it will be

with height is a lot easier, with grid and flex.

so it needs to be like the image you see, but with fonts.

[image]

like you see is correct with the height of the other two elements in the right.

example code (only for example)

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  /* square */
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  display: flex;
}

.item>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.another {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="big" style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="another">
      <div class="small" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
      <div class="small" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: it seems that span gets undesired padding on top and bottom. how can I delete that padding?

Comment: if nobody can solve this, tomorrow I will add a bounty, so maybe this question can interest more people. thanks as always. if you help and I will also give you more repo. just please try to find a better solution that is easy, and also why this happen with font-family in general?

Comment: look up `line-height`, which is different from `font-size`, and also consider/reset any top/bottom `margin`s that might apply by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a replication of your desired result from the screenshot. This solution uses `flex` properties to position the elements. It makes sense to group the "EUR" and the ".49" from the price into their own div and give it a `flex-column`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  --small-font: 1rem;
  font-family: poppins;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 1em;
}

.date {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
}

.right-side {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.price-container {
  display: flex;
}

.second-price-container {
  display: grid;
  font-size: var(--small-font);
}

.currency {
  padding-left: 7px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.currency,
.price-small {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.price-small {  
  font-weight: 500;
}

.price-big {
  font-size: calc(var(--small-font) * 5);
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
}

.price-small::before {
  content: ".";
}

.item .date {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>
    <div class="price-container">
      <span class="price-big">33</span>
      <div class="right-side">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small">49</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>
    <div class="price-container">
      <span class="price-big">33</span>
      <div class="right-side">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small">49</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>
    <div class="price-container">
      <span class="price-big">33</span>
      <div class="right-side">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small">49</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: this really perfect, super perfect, I need to see the code and understand it, but is perfect!

Comment: @stackdeveloper That doesn't make much sense, lol. Why is using the margin and padding **"the problem"**. `Margin` and `padding` are used simply to make it cleaner. My solution literally uses the exact same concept of `line-height` but I put it on `.price-big` instead of the entire container which is not needed. You will have to use `margin` and `padding` to clean up the other answer as well, mine is just already clean.

Comment: ok, your answer now is accepted because your answer is pixel perfect! thanks a lot!!!!!! is literally correct, really pixel perfect. sorry for the things happen before.

Answer (score 2):

Font size isn't the height.

`font-size * line-height == height`

I simply added `line-height: 1` to your `.price-container`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  --small-font: 1rem;
  font-family: poppins;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* space between copies of the container .item */
}

.item {
  display: grid;
}

.price-container {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 1;
}

.second-price-container {
  display: grid;
  font-size: var(--small-font);
}

.price-big {
  font-size: calc(var(--small-font) * 2);
  /* I think that since the grid layout has two text with 1rem height, it will be 2rem (but not seems to work) */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.price-small::before {
  content: ".";
}

.item .date {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>

    <div class="price-container">
      <div class="first-price-container">
        <span class="price-big"> 37 </span>
      </div>

      <div class="second-price-container">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small"> 49 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>

    <div class="price-container">
      <div class="first-price-container">
        <span class="price-big"> 37 </span>
      </div>

      <div class="second-price-container">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small"> 49 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <span class="date">Dom 07 Ago</span>

    <div class="price-container">
      <div class="first-price-container">
        <span class="price-big"> 37 </span>
      </div>

      <div class="second-price-container">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span>
        <span class="price-small"> 49 </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- and soo on... repeatedly, however after I will find the correct structure, I will create a function in javascript that generate it -->
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks, never thinked that there is a `line-height` property on CSS, thanks